# Quickly digitising several polygons based on classified raster output using ArcGIS Spatial Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, digitizing

I have a raster DTM of a river which I would like to split into 90 sections, each measuring 125m. I have used Euclidean Distance to outline each section by reclassifying the symbology to change colour at each appropriate interval. I would now like to extract each coloured section from the Euclidean Distance symbology to create individual rasters.

Is there a quick way to do this without having to manually cut around each section?

Here is what I am looking at
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Extract by Attributes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-by-attributes.htm) tool in the Spatial Analyst toolbox to create a new raster from a range of data.  You will need to sort out ModelBuilder iterators, or loop the Extract by Attributes tool with Python to get each of your classifications into different files.